# Servlet session not persisting

Tags: java, session, servlets, cookies

I have two servlets The first servlet is for getting and converting the phone number given according to the numpad similar to old phones. The telecommunication number (the first four digits) would be saved in a cookie while the converted number would be saved in the session object (this is required by the professor).

Example input: 0912 - ABCDEFG the output should be 0912-2223334.

The second servlet would output the data stored in the cookie and the session object via requestDispatcher but the session data becomes null when the input is also null.

servlet1:

```
public class ConvertServlet extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private String num;
    private String telco;
    private HttpSession session;
    private Cookie cTelco;
    private RequestDispatcher rd;

    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException 
    {
        String convertedNum = "";
        session = request.getSession();
        num = request.getParameter("number");
        telco = request.getParameter("telco");
        rd = request.getRequestDispatcher("Display");

        if (num != null || num != "")
        {
            for (byte i = 0; i < num.length(); i++)
            {
                switch(num.charAt(i))
                {
                    case 'A':
                    case 'B':
                    case 'C': convertedNum += "2"; break;
                    case 'D': 
                    case 'E':
                    case 'F': convertedNum += "3"; break;
                    case 'G':
                    case 'H': 
                    case 'I': convertedNum += "4"; break;
                    case 'J':
                    case 'K':
                    case 'L': convertedNum += "5"; break;
                    case 'M':
                    case 'N':
                    case 'O': convertedNum += "6"; break;
                    case 'P':
                    case 'Q':
                    case 'R':
                    case 'S': convertedNum += "7"; break;
                    case 'T':
                    case 'U':
                    case 'V': convertedNum += "8"; break;
                    case 'W':
                    case 'X':
                    case 'Y':
                    case 'Z': convertedNum += "9"; break;
                }
            }

            session.setAttribute("number", telco+convertedNum);
            cTelco = new Cookie("telco", telco);
        }
        response.addCookie(cTelco);
        rd.forward(request, response);
    }

}
```

servlet2:

```
public class DisplayNumber extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        response.setContentType("text/html");
        PrintWriter pw = response.getWriter();
        pw.println("The converted number is " + request.getSession().getAttribute("number"));
    }

}
```

Just assume that the codes have their respective import statements just to lessen the code length here in the post.

Comment: Is the question "why does the session value become null when I set it with a null"?

Comment: I mean if there is not input, the session object should persist and that should be the output of the code right?

Comment: You're comparing strings incorrectly, search SO for how to compare strings in Java. Session will have whatever you put in it.

Comment: Also, holding session-wide variables (`HttpSession` and friends) in application-wide artifact (`ConvertServlet`) is just plain wrong. Red flags raised.

Comment: I don't understand. Please elaborate.